# What is the most expensive property?

Tags: fable-3

I was just wondering what, where, and how much the most expensive property in Fable 3 is?

Answer (score 1):

here's a list of the properties and prices:

http://fable.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Fable_III_Properties

the top 3 most expensive were

1. 265,000 Gold @ Bowerstone Market - Bowerstone Broker (Pawnbroker)
2. 240,928 Gold @ Millifields - Fakeney Hall
3. 215,900 Gold @ Millifelds - Clixby-Stanners Manor

Comment: That's a good source, but could you also go through it and find out what is the most expensive propety? That is what's being asked here. It's also good to include such information in the actual answer because if the Wiki ever gets taken down, the answer will become useless otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The most expensive property is

Bowerstone Broker (Pawnbroker)  costing 265000